# slick slider causing issue in mobile view html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slick.js, slide

i have a website in html and php where i have used slick slider for the main slider, my code is like below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.customer-logos1').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 4500,
    arrows: false,
    dots: false,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    cssEase: 'linear',


  });
});
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="customer-logos1 slider" style="color:white;font-weight:400">


    <?php
$sliderbanner=$this->product->selectsliderbanner();

?>
    <?php foreach($sliderbanner as $slide){?>
    <div class="slide" style="width:100%">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-12" style="width: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;">
          <div style="background:#f7f7f7;height:100%;">
            <div class="tm-offer-content skewp1" style="text-align:center;padding-top:25%" id="siggl">

              <h4>
                <?=$slide->title?>
                  </h1>
                  <h6>
                    <?=$slide->description?>
              </h4>
              <span class="badge badge-warning" style="background:#A07F3D;color:white;font-size: inherit;
    padding: 0.55em 0.8em;"> <?=$slide->offer?></span>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-12" style="width: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;">
          <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>admin/uploads/about/<?=$slide->pimage1?>">
        </div>


        <div class="col-lg-4 col-12" style="width: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;">

          <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>admin/uploads/about/<?=$slide->pimage2?>">

        </div>
      </div>


    </div>

    <?php } ?>


  </div>


</section>
```

even though i havent set any width to the slides, the slides are showing misaligned in mostly mobile devices, in desktop devices the width issue is not much, in mobile the next slide images are overlapping in current slide, my live url is: [live](https://jewelit.in)
can anyone please tell me what is wrong in here, thanks in advance